How can I upload information from the database to the website? Almost decided, but stuck
I'm just learning and I'm stuck on a problem. I have 2 js files which are connected to an html file. The first file is me connecting to the database and writing all the data to an array and disconnecting. I made the second file a long time ago, it simply displays my array with styles in html. Separately, these files work. But I can’t figure out how to transfer the data that I received in the 1st file to the second file. I did some of the work based on information from forums, and some with prompts from chatGPT. But I got stuck on a problem. Tell.
const mysql = require('mysql');

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'root',
    database: 'films'
});
//подключаемся
connection.connect((err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Ошибка подключения: ' + err.stack);
        return;
    }
    console.log("Подключение успешно");
});


connection.query('SELECT * FROM movietest',(error, results,fields)=>{

    
    if(error) throw error;

// Результаты запроса хранятся в объекте results
    //массив для хранения
    const movieData=[];

    //проходимся по результатам
    results.forEach(element => {
        const movie={
            id:element.id,
            title:element.name,
            image:element.image_path,
            country:element.country,
            genre:element.genre,
            description:element.description,
            year:element.dateRelease,
            dateHD: element.dateHD

        };
        movieData.push(movie);
        console.log(movieData);
    });
});

//отключаемся disccon
connection.end((err)=>{
    if(err){
        console.log('Ошибка отключения '+err.stack);
        return;
    }else{
        console.log("Отключились");
    }
})

and second file
const filmsList=[{

    title:"Властелин колец",
    year:"1992",
    genre:"Фантастика",
    image:"../img/1.jpg",
    country:"США"
},

{
    title:"Форсаж",
    year:"1222",
    genre:"Боевик",
    image:"../img/Fast_&_Furious_9_(poster).jpg",
    country:"США"
},
{
    title:"Форсаж",
    year:"1222",
    genre:"Боевик",
    image:"../img/Fast_&_Furious_9_(poster).jpg",
    country:"США"
},
{
    title:"Форсаж",
    year:"1222",
    genre:"Боевик",
    image:"../img/Fast_&_Furious_9_(poster).jpg",
    country:"США"
},

{
    title:"Форсаж",
    year:"1222",
    genre:"Боевик",
    image:"../img/Fast_&_Furious_9_(poster).jpg",
    country:"США"
},
{
    title:"Форсаж",
    year:"1222",
    genre:"Боевик, Триллер, Комедия",
    image:"../img/Fast_&_Furious_9_(poster).jpg",
    country:"США"
},

];
console.log(filmsList);


function createMovieElement(movie){
    const movieElement=document.createElement('div');
    movieElement.classList.add('slider-info');

    movieElement.innerHTML=`
    <div class="slider-bg ">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="${movie.image}" alt="${movie.title}" >
    </a>
    <p>Год выпуска:${movie.year}</p>
    <p>Жанр: ${movie.genre}</p>
    <p>Страна: ${movie.country}</p>
  </div>
  <div class="favourites">
  <button class="favourites_button">
       <!-- icon666.com - MILLIONS vector ICONS FREE --><svg class="favourites_svg" viewBox="0 0 469.33333 469.33333"
         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
         <path
           d="m437.332031 192h-160v-160c0-17.664062-14.335937-32-32-32h-21.332031c-17.664062 0-32 14.335938-32 32v160h-160c-17.664062 0-32 14.335938-32 32v21.332031c0 17.664063 14.335938 32 32 32h160v160c0 17.664063 14.335938 32 32 32h21.332031c17.664063 0 32-14.335937 32-32v-160h160c17.664063 0 32-14.335937 32-32v-21.332031c0-17.664062-14.335937-32-32-32zm0 0" />
       </svg>
       <span class="favourites_button_text">В избранное</span>
  </button>
  </div>
  <h2 class="slider-info_title"><a href="#">${movie.title}</a></h2>
  <span class="slider-info_icons-right ico-red "></span>`
  
    return movieElement;
}

    const movieContainer = document.querySelector(".movie");
    filmsList.forEach(movie => {
        const movieElement = createMovieElement(movie);
        movieContainer.appendChild(movieElement);
    });




// ограничение элементов на страницу



const itemsPerPage =5; //сколько макс. на странице
const totalItems=filmsList.length; //количество элементов
let currentPage =1; //Текущая страница

function displayItemsOnPage(pageNumber) {
      // Очищаем текущие элементы
      movieContainer.innerHTML = "";

    // Вычисляем индекс начала и конца элементов для текущей страницы
    const startIndex = (pageNumber - 1) * itemsPerPage;
    const endIndex = Math.min(startIndex + itemsPerPage, totalItems);

    // Отображаем элементы от startIndex до endIndex на текущей странице
    const itemsToShow = filmsList.slice(startIndex, endIndex);
    itemsToShow.forEach(movie => {
        const movieElement = createMovieElement(movie);
        movieContainer.appendChild(movieElement);
    });
}
// Показываем первую страницу при загрузке страницы
displayItemsOnPage(currentPage);```
   



You could wrap most/all of the logic from the first file in a function and call that function it from the second file. This way you have full control over when data is fetched and where the results are sent.

You can wrap up the query part in one function and that function should return an array of movies after that export it from that file and call that function in another file and you will get the array of movies.
